# Laravel file Uploading returning null when size is large

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, filepond

I am trying to upload videos using laravel, filepond and s3 bucket. When file size is greater than 5Mb aws is not returning anything and even the file is not getting uploaded. But when the file size is less than 5Mb it's getting uploaded and I am able to get the s3 file path.

```
public function upload_video(Request $request){
    if ($request->hasFile('link')) {
        $video_link = Storage::disk('s3')->put('videos', $request->file('link'));

        return $video_link;
    }
}
```

Comment: This sounds more like a file size limit of the web server or php - I'd start there.   What do the laravel logs say?   Which web server are you using (nginx, apache, etc.)?

Comment: For development i am using Apache(wampp) server but in production as i am using nginx

Comment: And also there are no logs

Comment: Ok - is this happening in both Dev and Prod?  Have you checked the `client_max_body_size` for nginx?   What does php have set for `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`?

Comment: It's happening both dev and prod also I have increased upload_max_filesize, post_max_size still same issue

Comment: Have you set the PHP runtime to debug mode? And don't forget to verbose the debug log for easier to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure PHP.INI settings were allowing uploads high enough. PHP.INI only allows 2M by default, so increased this limit to 20M. And Amazon S3 doesn’t like files over 5 MB uploading in one go, instead, you need to stream it through.

please use the given reference link to solve this issue by using streaming from server to S3.

https://www.webdesign101.net/laravel-s3-uploads-failing-when-uploading-large-files-in-laravel-5-8/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upload big files you should use streams. Here’s the code to do it:

```
$disk = Storage::disk('s3');
$disk->put($targetFile, fopen($sourceFile, 'r+'));
```

Comment: It's not working